# Memory warning received while processing the >1.4MB size image in Core Image filters ios?

Tags: iphone, ios5, image-processing, uiimage, core-image

In my app i am using core image filters
The below code i am using for

**my code:**

```
- (UIImage*)applyRGBWithRed:(float)red withGreen:(float)green withBlue:(float)blue
{
        ciimage=[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
       // Make the filter
    CIFilter *colorMatrixFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"]; // 2
    [colorMatrixFilter setDefaults]; // 3
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:ciimage forKey:kCIInputImageKey]; // 4
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:red Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"]; // 5
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:green Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"]; // 6
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:blue W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"]; // 7
    [colorMatrixFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1] forKey:@"inputAVector"]; // 8z


    // Get the output image recipe
    CIImage *outputImage = [colorMatrixFilter outputImage];  // 9

    // Create the context and instruct CoreImage to draw the output image recipe into a CGImage
    context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]]; // 10
    self.saveImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return self.saveImage;
  }
```

while i was processing the large image[i.e greater than 1.4 MB size] it gives memory warning  and crashes the app.

**why it leads to crash?
how can i mange this scenario?**

Any advice or idea highly appreciate-able . i struck in this more than a week...

Thanks in advance....

**while running in the pro-filer it gives the following out put** 
[image]

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @BorisProhaska sorry i updated my question ...

Comment: maybe you can "split" your large image into smaller parts, apply the filer on each of them, and combine them back to a large image? (as I can see you are applying color matrix filter, which should be splitable) Another suggestion is switching to the GPUImage framework (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), it is faster than CoreImage

Comment: @Owen hi thanks for your reply.... Do you have any sample or tutorial regarding this will be more helpful for me

Comment: @Spynet unfortunately I am not on my development machine, if no one comes up with a better answer I can write sample code for you in 10 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can "split" your large image into smaller parts, apply the filer on each of them, and combine them back to a large image?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]; // The Big image
NSMutableArray *croppedImages = [NSMutableArray array];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGSize cropSize = CGSizeMake(500, 500); // The size of each "small image"
// Step 1: Produce the small images and save to disk
for (CGFloat x = 0; x < imageSize.width; x += cropSize.width)
{
    for (CGFloat y = 0; y < imageSize.height; y += cropSize.height)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cropSize);
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-x, -y)];
        UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cropped_%f_%f.png",x,y]];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cropped);
        [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        imageData = nil;

        [croppedImages addObject:path];
    }
}
// Release the big image (assume we are using ARC)
image = nil;
// Step 2: Apply the filter to the small images and re-save them
for (NSString *path in croppedImages)
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Apply your filter to img here

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    imageData = nil;
}
// Step 3: Combine the small images back to a big one
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
for (CGFloat x = 0; x < imageSize.width; x += cropSize.width)
{
    for (CGFloat y = 0; y < imageSize.height; y += cropSize.height)
    {
        NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cropped_%f_%f.png",x,y]];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

        [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    }
}
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// Step 4: Optionally remove the temporary files
for (NSString *path in croppedImages)
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
}
```

Obviously, it will be slow.